# Quel serait un synonyme de « peu importe que »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Souvent, j’emplois le terme « gros » ou sa forme féminine pour renforcer une qualification injurieuse, comme dans « gros paresseux », « gros cochon », peu importe la condition physique de mon interlocuteur, qu’il soit bien en chair ou non.

Comment: Alors traiter une femme de grosse cochonne ne décrit pas une condition physique? Il me semble que cela serait surdéterminé par plusieurs facteurs.

Comment: Eh bien ici il faudrait tenir compte du contexte dans lequel la qualification est lancée… » « Grosse cochonne », sans contexte, pourrait effectivement prêter à des interprétations multiples.

Comment: Pour ma part j’entendais « gros cochon » ou « grosse cochonne » au sens d’une personne aux mœurs légères et à la sexualité débridée.

Comment: Un homme ou une femme porté-e sur le sexe.

Comment: La question concerne-elle *peu importe (que)* ou est-ce une discussion ouverte sur le contenu de la phrase donnée en exemple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ici, tu peux remplacer ***peu importe*** par ***quelle que soit***.

Answer (score 0):

Aussi avec la locution prépositive [*indépendamment de*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ind%C3%A9pendamment/42533).